# Good and full implementation of RSS feeds in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rss

I've seen a few examples of RSS Feeds in ASP.NET MVC, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915/rss-feeds-in-aspnet-mvc), and some samples in projects (like Oxite), but none of them are complete.

Eg. None of them check for the header

```
  If-Modified-Since
```

in the request, to save bandwidth.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so I stop here asking for some directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this. Please comment or edit the post if you find any error or better way to do it.

### RssController

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Syndication
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Web.HttpContext

Function MasterRSS()
    Dim baseURL As String = "http://www.mysite.com"
    Dim feed As New SyndicationFeed("MySite - Master RSS", "", New Uri(baseURL))
    ''//Add a custom attribute.
    Dim xqName As New XmlQualifiedName("CustomAttribute")
    feed.AttributeExtensions.Add(xqName, "Value")

    Dim sp As New SyndicationPerson("jerry@mysite.com", "Jerry Seinfeld", "http://Jerry.blog.com")
    feed.Authors.Add(sp)

    Dim category As New SyndicationCategory("Category")
    feed.Categories.Add(category)

    feed.Contributors.Add(New SyndicationPerson("cosmo@mysite.com", "Cosmo Kramer", "http://kramer.blog.com"))
    feed.Copyright = New TextSyndicationContent("MySite 2008")
    feed.Description = New TextSyndicationContent("My description")

    ''//Add a custom element.
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim feedElement As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("CustomElement")
    feedElement.InnerText = "Some text"
    feed.ElementExtensions.Add(feedElement)

    feed.Generator = "Custom"
    feed.Id = "MySiteFeedID"
    feed.ImageUrl = New Uri("http://www.mysite.com/content/images/logo.png")

    ''//Items
    Dim ModifiedSince As Date
    If Not Date.TryParse(Current.Request.Headers("If-Modified-Since"), ModifiedSince) Then
        ModifiedSince = Date.Today.AddDays(-30) ''//Or whatever make sense to you.         
    Else
        ModifiedSince.AddMinutes(-5) ''//Just in case, we do not want to miss any item. 
    End If

    ''//the list of items.
    Dim items As New List(Of SyndicationItem)()


    Dim db As New mainDataContext
    Dim textContent As TextSyndicationContent, Item As SyndicationItem

    ''//Then send the list of post, comments, whatever.
    Dim Posts = (From p In db.Posts Where c.Date >= ModifiedSince Order By p.Date Descending)
    For Each Post In Posts
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.AppendFormat("<p>{0}</p>", Post.FullText)
        textContent = New TextSyndicationContent(sb.ToString, TextSyndicationContentKind.Html)
        Item = New SyndicationItem("Post " + Post.PostID.ToString, textContent, New Uri(baseURL + "/Post/View/" + Post.PostID.ToString), "Post" + Post.PostID.ToString, Post.Date)
        items.Add(Item)
    Next


    If items.Count = 0 Then
        ''//send a 304 to the browser.
        Return View("304")
    End If

    feed.Items = items
    feed.Language = "es-ar"
    feed.LastUpdatedTime = (From i In items Select i.LastUpdatedTime Order By LastUpdatedTime Descending).FirstOrDefault

    ''//Not needed in this sample.
    ''//Dim link As New SyndicationLink(New Uri("http://server/link"), "alternate", "Link Title", "text/html", 1000)
    ''//feed.Links.Add(link)

    ViewData("feed") = feed
    Return View("Rss")

End Function
```

### Rss View (rss.aspx)

```
Dim htmlwriter As System.IO.Stream = Response.OutputStream
Dim rssWriter As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(htmlwriter)
Dim feed As System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed = ViewData("feed")
Dim rssFormatter As New System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Rss20FeedFormatter(feed)
rssFormatter.WriteTo(rssWriter)
rssWriter.Close()
```

This way, you can reuse the view

Comment: It seems you're confusing the server variable name with the actual header name: Current.Request.Headers("HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE") should be Current.Request.Headers("If-Modified-Since")

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen it implement HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE, but I would look into using the SyndicationFeed class.  It makes it very simple to handle feeds without any parsing.  I am currently using it for Atom feeds, but it is supposed to work for RSS as well:

```
function SyndicationFeed GetFeed(string url) {
  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
  SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
  return feed;
}

public ActionResult ShowFeed()
{
  string feedUrl = "somefeedurl";
  SyndicationFeed feed = GetFeed(feedUrl);
  return View(feed);
}
```

...then in the view:

```
  <%foreach (var item in ViewData.Model.Items) { %>
    <li><a href="<%=item.Id %>"><%=item.Title.Text %></a></li>
  <% } %>
```

Comment: P.S.  The class is in the System.ServiceModel.Web assembly

Comment: Your solution is for consuming feeds, not publishing (as asked)

Comment: Getting this error in view.
CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability`, `SetExpires` and `SetMaxAge` then the ASP.NET caching system will take care of this for you - it understands the If-Modified-Since header. [This blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx) shows how you can create an MVC Action Filter to do the necessary in MVC.

Comment: Yes, but I want to go a little further after the cache expires and check if there are new items after If-Modified-Since