# RSS management in MVC3 applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rss

My question is mainly inspired by the issues raised in response to [RSS Feeds in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915/rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc) - a question that looks like it's drawn more than average amount to attention (ranks high in google's "RSS feeds from asp.net MVC" return. Because 2 distinctly different approaches have been voted up I'm hoping folks will find it worthwhile to re-examime the core question: What's the best way to handle the management of RSS feed in an MVC framework.

In the time since that question was asked:

> 1. Have the releases of .net v4 and/or MVC3;
> 2. Experience acquired in the real world; or
> 3. 3rd party libs

changed a 'best practices' approach to handling RSS feeds?

Comment: duplicate of [RSS Feeds in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915/rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc) - the answer hasn't changed at all

Comment: Seems so, i've entered the following as comment at that question: Just to update this question as of 18 months following last edit - It seemed reasonable to question 'have things changed with iterations to both .net and mvc that would change how we approach the problem of feed management'?  The consensus (via a different SO thread) is that, 'No fundamental changes - this remains your best set of alternatives.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

steve, the response on the linked post by Eran Kampf is, imo, the real 'best practice'.  It's clean, concise, portable, and ensures that you follow the RSS feed format standards.

Answer (score 0):

In short I don't know of any additions to the framework that enable this out of the box.

Someone else might have a better answer but I would do something like this -> [Good post about creating an rss feed.](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/01/11/asp-net-mvc-rss-feed-action-result.aspx)

But that article is from Jan 2009.

This post from Oct 2009 shows you how to create an RssResult inheriting from ActionResult -> http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/rssresult-aspnet-mvc-rss-actionresult/

The second link is probably the nicer way to do it.