# Is it possible to output a formatted RSS feed to a partial view by writing to the html response?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rss, partial-views

Some answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915/rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc) question describe how to inherit the ActionResult class and return an instance of it from an action method in the controller class. The custom ActionResult overrides the ExecuteResult method in which a formatted RSS feed is written to the html response. But how would you do this if you wanted the RSS feed output to a partial view?