# Can I create a Razor view that renders Rss in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, rss

I know that to generate rss I can use built-in classes like SyndicationFeed and Rss20FeedFormatter. Also I know that it can be done with custom classes and aspx view.

But if I want to create custom feed objects and custom view, can I do this using razor?

Here is my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<div><b>Description:</b> @Model.Description</div>
<div><b>Language:</b> @Model.Language</div>
<a href="@Model.Url" class="averageLink">Subscribe to this Feed</a>

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <h3>
        Title: @item.Title 
    </h3>
    <div>
        <img width="75" height="75" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Store", new { productId = item.ProductId })"/>
    </div>
    <div><b>Description:</b> @item.Description</div>
    <div><b>Creator:</b> @item.Creator</div>
    <div><b>Date published</b> @item.Published</div>
    <div>
        <a href="@item.Url" class="averageLink">place order on Ozon</a>
    </div>
    @Html.ActionLink("go to item", "ItemInformation", "Store", new {itemId = item.ItemId}, new {@class = "averageLink"})
}
</channel>
</rss>
```

Other questions:

1) I don't know how exactly to implement "subscription" link: what value to assign to the @Model.Url?

2) It generates html, mabby instead I need to serialize my feed objects into xml document and return it with a custom XmlResult : ActionResult?

Edit 1: Mabby I somehow can use built-in classes and custom feed model together?

Edit 2: The reason I don't want to use the existing classes is because I need to use Html.ActionLink() and Url.Action() helpers. If I serialize feed object into xml how would I use these helper methods?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: You seem to forget from your previous question that an rss feed is an xml file. Putting html in it is not going to work.

Comment: So, what I can do is to serialize my custom feed object into xml? How to implement "subscribe" link then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view code is producing html, not the xml that is needed for an rss feed (you are including elements like `div` and `h3` that are part of html).

To produce a view that outputs RSS, the layout of the view should replicate the [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Example) [standard](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html).

For example:

```
@model MyProject.Models.RssModel
@{ Layout = null }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>@model.FeedTitle</title>
  <description>@model.FeedDescription</description>
  <link>@model.FeedLink</link>
  <lastBuildDate>@model.LastBuildDate</lastBuildDate>
  <pubDate>@model.PubDate</pubDate>
  <ttl>@model.Ttl</ttl>
  @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
  {
    <item>
      <title>@item.Title</title>
      <description>@item.Description</description>
      <link>@item.Url</link>
      <guid>@item.Id</guid>
      <pubDate>@item.PublicationDate</pubDate>
    </item>   
  }  
</channel>
</rss>
```

However, you may want to consider a different approach: returning a result from your Controller Action that will generate the RSS directly. You can see examples of this approach in [this blog post](http://damieng.com/blog/2010/04/26/creating-rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc) or described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11920/51).